# Building pluggable apps: how to include forks of popular libraries and prevent name conflicts?

Tags: python, django, plugins, namespaces

I'm building an app that I'm trying to keep pluggable. The only problem is that I need to modify `django-mailer` slightly so that my app can keep track of which emails have been sent / not and have access to the email contents.

What's the best approach to make sure this doesn't conflict with others using `django-mailer`, or any other python library I decide to fork / tweak for my own app?

Should I rename mailer in my fork and all of its relevant imports? Am I missing something easier?

Comment: Do your mods to django-mailer break it for other apps? If not, then don't worry, everyone can use your version.

Comment: You could receive signals from django-mailer in your own app and leave it unmodified? It sounds like the things you're trying to do with it don't require actual modification.

Comment: @Spacedman it would break it as I want to modify a field on the `MessageLog` object. The problem is that the core mailer `engine` class immediately `delete()`s the Message object while creating a `MessageLog`. I suppose I could write my own model that stores MessageLog -> Message relationships, and essentially copy-and-paste the `mailer.engine` to add the ML->M relationship.

Comment: @moopet - Signals briefly crossed my mind. How would you communicate from a Message to MessageLog?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a function. Create a function that does both things:

- Make sure you can get hold of what you want afterwards
- Make sure the message is sent.

Or you can do some more heavy plumbing. Make sure to document it well and try to make other people not try this at home for every futile purpose, instead, contact the Django or Django-mailer teams and ask them if they can arrange a better solution.

- decorate the EmailMessage class from the django.core.mail module: make sure that when a message is successfully sent, the information you want is also delivered somewhere else.

  ```
  # wrappedmailer.py
  from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

  class WrappedEmailMessage(object):
      def __init__(self, message):
          self.__message = message
          # more initialization

      # override all EmailMessage methods:
      # do what you want with what is provided,
      # then return self.__message.method(...)
  ```
- Then when your application is initialized, before django-mailer is loaded, you can do the following:

  ```
     import django.core.mail
     import newmailer

     django.core.mail.EmailMessage = newmailer.WrappedEmailMessage
  ```

The django.core.mail module stays in the cache within the same Python process, so whenever django.core.mail is imported, the EmailMessage class will in fact be the WrappedEmailMessage class.

Comment: I like the idea of wrapping `EmailMessage`. Unfortunately, my primary question still remains: I am needing to modify `django-mailer` itself (or any other app) and curious how to handle it. These are changes that cannot be monkey patched: model-level changes. How do I prevent it from conflicting with django-mailers? Is it standard to rename the package and every import defined in it?

Comment: If changing `django-mailer` is a primary requirement, copy it to a package `mypackages.mymailer` (not mypackages.mailer, so that the contenttypes framework doesn't get too confused). Then change the code as required. You can then still use both versions, but you will always know if you use the original or the modified version.

Comment: So it's standard to rename everything so the new mailer doesn't import the old mailer? It seems like a decent amount of work to keep all import lines updated, but I can't really see another solution (purpose of this question). This would suck terribly in a bigger package with lots of code.

Comment: Therefore, small is beautiful.